# Data for specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

My report gets data for the 1st of the current month. Let's say the 1st has still not come then how would I make the report show the data for the 1st of the previous month.

Thanks.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you mean your table doesn't yet have any data for the first of the current month, then you can either check for that and then decide which month to query; or query both months' data and discard the previous month if you have anything for the current month in the result set. But that affects aggregation depending on what you're reporting on. It's rather vague at the moment.

Comment: This is what I did to get the 1st of the current month:
Date = to_date('1-'||to_char(sysdate,'MON-RRRR'),'dd-mon-rrrr'). For example, if the 1st of January has no data, then I want to display data from the 1st of December.

Comment: Surely the 1st of the current month has by definition always come?

Comment: You could then use add_months(ProgressDate,-1) to get the 1st of last month.

Comment: `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` will give you the first of the current month more simply. But you haven't said how you're determining there is no data, or how you're running the query. Might be simple to run it, see how many rows were found, and run it again with the previous month (via `add_months`). Too many unknowns in your process though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `select top 1` from your table, filtering by `extract(day from yourDateColumn) = 1` to get only the rows with the data for the 1st day of any month, and order them in descending order by your date column (`order by yourDateColumn desc`), so that you always get the 1st day of the last available month in your table.

[Docs for Oracle EXTRACT function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#i1017161)